# how to align divs vertically in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I have the following html divs :

```
...
<body>
<div id="barChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;float:left; "></div>
<div id="stats_div" style="width: 350px; height: 250px; float:left;"></div>
<div id="lineChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px; "></div>
<div id="cdfChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;"></div>
</body>
...
```

what I am trying to do is to display the first div ( contains a bar chart) and the second div(contains some text fro the chart) next to each other, then below them display the other two divs (contain other charts) one after the other vertically i.e. I want it to look like:

[image: desired]

and what i get currently is :

[image: actual]

cdfChart_div (div4) is getting displayed on top of lineChart_div(div3).
What CSS style do i need to use to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the `div` that comes immediately after the *floated* `stats_div`:

`style="clear:left;"`

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CBu2f/1/)

Full code:

```
...
<body>
<div id="barChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;float:left; "></div>
<div id="stats_div" style="width: 350px; height: 250px; float:left;"></div>
<div id="lineChart_div" style="clear:left; width: 600px; height: 250px; "></div>
<div id="cdfChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;"></div>
</body>
...
```

Since `stats_div` is floated, its contents are taken out of the normal flow. Thus, the contents of the next `div` that is part of the normal flow does not make space for the contents of `stats_div`. You have have to `clear` one side of the next `div` if you want its contents to come after the contents of the previous floated `div`.  Often you'll see `clear: both`, which works on either edge of the normal flow `div`.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
<body>
<div style="overflow:auto">
  <div id="barChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;float:left; "></div>
  <div id="stats_div" style="width: 350px; height: 250px; float:left;"></div>
</div>
<div id="lineChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px; "></div>
<div id="cdfChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;"></div>
```

Comment: Keep the css inline isn't a good choice (know that the user write that code, but help him understand)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look to my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XeNA3/4/)

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="barChart_div" style="width: 145px; height: 250px;">aa</div>
<div id="stats_div" style="width: 350px; height: 250px;">bb</div>
<div id="lineChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;">cc</div>
<div id="cdfChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;">dd</div>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
#barChart_div, #stats_div { float:left; }
#lineChart_div { clear:left; }
```

**Explaination**

First of all remember that have an "in-line" CSS isn't a good practise. You have to prefer external CSS or internal (i.e. header) css.

However let's see that example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yWcDh/). 
As you can see, if you don't specify differently all your divs will result in an "ideal column". That's because the normal flow of the "html parser" will put them in that position.

If you do this with span element, instead, you obtain all the element on the same "line" (if they can stand and don't overflow, obviously). You can see that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PnuqV/).

When you tell `float:left` you're "forcing" the div to be floated at the "right margin" of the previous element.

Now, due to the second element floated, the third element will act at the same way.
For act as "standard" you have to use `clear:left` that will restore the "normal" behaviour

Comment: it works.. but could you please explain how it works this way?

Comment: DonCallisto: since `barChart_div` is floated right, and since `lineChart_div` is floated left, when you make the viewport wider, `lineChart_div` ends up on the first line breaking the layout.  If you made the viewport even wider, then `cdfChart_div` would end up on the first line to the right of `lineChart_div`.

Comment: @JohnB : Updated ... Didn't noticed at the first time, but in the "explaination" i'll forget to update the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can, change your source order so the stats_div comes first, then use float:right on *just* it.

Comment: it works.. but the second div goes very far to the right.. and I want it to be just next to the first one without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="stats_div" style="width: 350px; height: 250px; float:right; background-color:#0099CC; border:1px solid black">custom</div>
<div id="barChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;float:left; background-color:#0099CC; border:1px solid black">1</div>
<div id="lineChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px; float:left;background-color:#0099CC; border:1px solid black">2</div>
<div id="cdfChart_div" style="width: 600px; height: 250px;float:left; background-color:#0099CC; border:1px solid black">3</div>
```

paste it to your html, effect will be visible