# Divs Vertical in HTML

Tags: html, css

How to have div vertically in HTML.

When we use this code:

```
<div>Some Text 1 | </div>
<div>Some Text 2 | </div>
<div>Some Text 3 | </div>
<div>Some Text 4 | </div>
<div>Some Text 5 | </div>
<div>Some Text 6 | </div>
<div>Some Text 7 | </div>
```

The result is:

```
Some Text 1 |
Some Text 2 |
Some Text 3 |
Some Text 4 |
Some Text 5 |
Some Text 6 |
Some Text 7 |
```

How to get results like:

```
Some Text 1 | Some Text 2 | Some Text 3 | Some Text 4 | Some Text 5 | Some Text 6 | Some Text 7
```

Same as above with a vertical scroll

I tried this StackOverflow Question but it is not the same as I wanted, [how to align divs vertically in html and css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246291/how-to-align-divs-vertically-in-html-and-css)

Comment: I think where you stated vertical you meant horizontal, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to align divs vertically in html and css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246291/how-to-align-divs-vertically-in-html-and-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep the divs in a wrapper div with display flex property;

```
<div style="display: flex;">
  <div>Some Text 1 | </div>
  <div>Some Text 2 | </div>
  <div>Some Text 3 | </div>
  <div>Some Text 4 | </div>
  <div>Some Text 5 | </div>
  <div>Some Text 6 | </div>
  <div>Some Text 7 | </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's good to remember that, with flex, more display options can be set, if needed, by setting its other properties, like 'flex-direction', 'align-items', etc.

Comment: I found this as best answer, can I get a help how to have some space (20 - 40 px) between two divs in the same code, [have this source code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRLTAJIH8LLJ)

Comment: Add margin: 0 15px; on the inner divs

Comment: The url you gave is of w3 schools... Do you want  space in the above example that you asked in ques or w3schools url ?

Comment: I want in w3schools url, and also I think the width of the div is not same as I mentioned in the w3schools url...`<div class="w3-card-4" style="width:30%">`

Comment: Use flex-wrap: wrap; style on the same div where you added display: flex;

Comment: I updated code and saved it. Is this something like what you want ? https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRLU8MZGQQDR

Comment: Something like that, but I need all divs in one row (with scroll) not a set of 3 columns

Comment: I have created one more layout. This one has nowrap property with horizontal scroll. Chose whichever suits you :) https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRLUBIMR4ONO

Comment: I think my last comment has what you desired.

Comment: I tried your last updated codes with proper images, **[updated code](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRMNTBRQTCOE)** but it is not properly displayed as I wanted.

Comment: Add align-items: flex-start; on .w3-container div  https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRMO3ER74MT2

Comment: Tried latest codes but yet the display is https://i.imgur.com/P2bv346.png

Comment: Its working fine for me. Which browser are you checking ?

Comment: Chrome, can I have your ss please

Comment: Something is wrong at: `.w3-container {
 display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
}`

Comment: I want something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRNUB7C7C8UG

Comment: Ok, have a look at this comment, please.

Comment: I have fixed the design in fist template. Check the latest code https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FRNVBRBHPAFP

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to do that, but I think the most simple ones are:

1. You can change your div tag to a span.
2. Change the CSS 'display' property to 'inline-block' or 'inline'.

It might show you the result you're looking for.

To add the scroll, you might want to look on the parent tag of your divs/spans and add the CSS 'overflow-x' property and set it to 'scroll'.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of writing the separators in HTML there's an easy way around with only CSS selectors.

You can use the pseudo selectors: `:after` and `:last-child` to select the corresponding `div` and set `|` after the elements with the property `content`:

```css
.item {
    display: inline-block;
}

.item:after {
    content: ' |';
}
.item:last-child:after {
    content: '';
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four</div>
  <div class="item">Five</div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could keep the content inside HTML and use `span` or just set the `display` property of `.item` to `inline-block`.

**Edit:** there's a shorthand version to set `content: ' |'` on the right elements (i.e. all of them but the last one) with the operator `+`. Heres the code:

```css
.item {
  display: inline-block;
}

.item+.item:before {
  content: ' | ';
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item">One</div>
  <div class="item">Two</div>
  <div class="item">Three</div>
  <div class="item">Four</div>
  <div class="item">Five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this answer is far more better then the automatic answer : "Get rid of everything! Use flexbox!"

Answer (score 0):

you just need define "display: inline;" attribute in style or css file.
css:

```
div{
display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use responsive web design.

## CSS:

```
.container{
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  padding: 0% 0; /* 0px/1200px = 0 */
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.grid1{ width:8.33333333333333%;float:left; }       /* 100px/1200px=0,0833333333333333=8,33333333333333% */
.grid2{ width: 16.66666666666667%;float:left; }         /* 200px/1200px=0,1666666666666667=16,66666666666667% */
.grid3{ width: 25%;float:left; }            /* 300px/1200px=0,25=25% */
.grid4{ width:33.33333333333333%;float:left; }         /* 400px/1200px=0,3333333333333333=33,33333333333333% */
.grid5{ width:41.66666666666667%;float:left; }      /* 500px/1200px=0,4166666666666667=41,66666666666667% */
.grid6{ width:50%; float:left; }                /* 600px/1200px=0,5=50% */
.grid7{ width:58.33333333333333%; float:left; }     /* 700px/1200px=0,5833333333333333=58,33333333333333% */
.grid8{ width:66.66666666666667%; float:left; }                 /* 800px/1200px=0,6666666666666667=66,66666666666667% */
.grid9{ width:75%; float:left; }            /* 900px/1200px=0,75=75% */
.grid10{ width:83.33333333333333%; float:left; }                /* 1000px/1200px=0,8333333333333333=83,33333333333333% */
.grid11{ width:91.66666666666667%; float:left; }            /* 1100px/1200px=0,9166666666666667=91,66666666666667% */
.grid12{ width: 100%; float:left; }             /* 1200px/1200px=1=100% */

   @media screen and (max-width : 705px) {
.grid1,
.grid2,
.grid3,
.grid4,
.grid5,
.grid6,
.grid7,
.grid8,
.grid9,
.grid10,
.grid11,
.grid12 {
  width: 100%;
}}
```

## Web page:

```
  <div class="grid1">Some Text 1 | </div>
  <div class="grid1">Some Text 2 | </div>
  <div class="grid1">Some Text 3 | </div>
  <div class="grid1">Some Text 4 | </div>
  <div class="grid1">Some Text 5 | </div>
  <div class="grid1">Some Text 6 | </div>
  <div class="grid6">Some Text 7 | </div>
```